# Undocumented '-c' option for Bash's 'declare'?

Tags: bash, declare, undocumented-behavior

I was playing around with Bash variables and mistakenly used the `-c` option (for `const`) to `declare` instead of the correct `-r` option to create a `readonly` variable.  To my surprise, the variable retained the `-c` attribute and capitalized the first letter of whatever value I assigned.

This behavior is not listed in `declare`'s usage, either within the `declare --help` output or on Bash's info page.  It seems to be incompatible with ksh's `typeset`, though the `-u` and `-l` options are compatible.

Is this a well-known undocumented feature?  Is it generally available?

Comment: This reminds me of the undocumented expansion to toggle case: `${foo~}` toggles the first character of `$foo`, and `${foo~~}` toggles all characters.

Comment: See related [Bug Bash Mailing-List](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash), on Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:10:07 +0100, Mikael Fridh wrote: [declare -c still undocumented.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-02/msg00074.html)

Comment: @LéaGris sounds like someone should file a new bug there, "declare -c still still undocumented" :)

Comment: @hobbs here you are: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-11/msg00054.html

Comment: Update: In Bash 5.2, released in September, 2022, this feature still exists, and is still undocumented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`declare -c`, `-l`, and `-u` appear to have been added all together in bash 4.0 (introduced in 4.0-rc1), as long as the `--enable-casemod-attributes` configure flag isn't disabled (it's enabled by default). There are tests for them (in `tests/casemod.tests`). Why `-c` was never documented is a mystery.

Comment: While writing this question, I dug through the Bash source code and discovered much the same.  However, searching Google yielded no results.  I'm hopeful that the next person to search will discover this answer and find it useful.

Comment: [On Thu, 19 Mar 2009 09:37:06 -0400, Chet Ramey wrote: `Correct.  I'm not sure the capitalization feature will survive.  If it makes it into the next version, I will add the documentation.`](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2009-03/msg00152.html) Look like He forgot about it:

Comment: @LéaGris aha! Good sleuthing.

Comment: @LéaGris And now it looks as if he might get rid of it. :(  But yeah, good sleuthing.